# Javascript loading mp3 file as blob

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that for various reasons I cant change any of the code inside, the parameter for `e` that is passed to the function is a file selector mp3 file that the user "uploads"

this is the structure of the function-

```
let handleFileSelection = function(e) {
        fileStore = e.target.files[0];
        //go off and do other stuff with fileStore
}
```

this is the structure of fileStore when the file selector passes an mp3 to the function-

```
lastModified:1508423505000
lastModifiedDate:Thu Oct 19 2017 15:31:45 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) {}
name:"audioFile.mp3"
size:5571549
type:"audio/mp3"
webkitRelativePath:""
```

is it possible to pass a locally stored mp3 file to the function instead in such a way that the fileStore will have the same information ?

To clarify: The function currently accepts an mp3 file from a file selector, I need it to accept a locally stored mp3 file and for the fileStore to have the exact same information as if i was passing a file from the file selector, is this possible without modifying the function ?

Comment: If you just mean inside a standard web browser, the answer is no.  For security reasons files selected in browser have to be done by the user.

Comment: I don't need to use the file selector as such, just create a blob/file that looks identical to one that would be returned by the file selector

Comment: Have you tried using `new Blob()`?

Comment: yeah, new blob doesn't have the same structure as the one the file selector returns

Comment: Some properties from the Blob contructor don't get passed, but you can add them later.. eg. `var a = new Blob([1,2,3], {type:"audio/mp3"}); a.name="audioFile.mp3";`

Comment: this worked but it seems to break the audio (no audio in the blob)

Comment: Were are you getting your MP3 audio data from, in my example the bytes `1,2,3` are of course not a valid MP3,.